# Django filter on prefetch

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following query:

```
prefetch = Prefetch('books', queryset=Book.objects.filter(is_published=True),
                             to_attr='published_books')

profiles = Profile.objects.prefetch_related(prefetch)
```

This selects all profiles and populates them with published books.
However, I want only profiles, that actually have published books (in other words `len(profile.published_books) > 0`).

How can I achieve it in orm?

UPDATE:

```
class Book(Model):
    profile = ForeignKey(Profile, related_name="books", related_query_name="book")
    name = CharField(max_length=250)
    is_published = BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('profile', 'name'),)
```

Comment: Could you add related model, please?

Comment: Done. Please, see update.

Answer (score 0):

```
 profile_ids = Profile.objects.filter(book__is_published=True).values_list("pk", flat=True).distinct()
 profiles = Profile.objects.filter(pk__in=profile_ids).prefetch_related(prefetch)
```

this will result a subquery that locate correct profile ids and then return any profile that match one of these ids.
use of `distinct` function has no effect on result but I am guessing it could improve performance (not really sure)